# I need help fixing this coding problem where I am getting a Key Error

Tags: python, html, mysql, python-venv

I am trying to get an ID value from a form from an html page, but I am getting a KeyError for the value I am calling in app.py

**relevant code from `tripd.html`**

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
    <form action="POST">
        <select id="ID" name ="ID">
        {% for mem in membies %}
            <option value="{{mem['ID']}}">{{mem['name']}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <a href="{{url_for('addatt', trip_id=trip_id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Attendee</button></a>
    </form> 
</div>
```

**relevant code from `app.py`**

```py
@app.route('/trips/<trip_id>/attendees/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def addatt(trip_id):
    member_id=request.form['ID']
    database.add_member_trip(trip_id, member_id)
    return redirect(url_for('trip', trip_id=trip_id))
```

```
# error message: KeyError: 'ID'
# relevant line: member_id=request.form['ID']
```

Comment: `name ="ID"` there can't be a space here.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're trying to process the form without checking first if it's a GET or POST request.  Form data is (generally) only present on POST requests.